# CakePHP 3 Entity default field value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a entity named "View" and this entity has a attribute named "datetime" (the name of entity and field are not relevant).

I would like to set a default value to it inside CakePHP instead of defining it on database.

On my entity class I defined:

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

class View extends Entity
{

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'id' => false,
    ];

    protected function _getDatetime($datetime)
    {
        return Time::now();
    }
}
```

And when I try to save it in a method of Model Table class (ViewTable):

```
public function registerView(User $user){
    $view = $this->newEntity();
    $view->user = $user;
    $this->save($view);
}
```

Nothing happens, my "datetime" field is saved as '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

My question is: How can I set a default value for a entity so when I call `$this->newEntity()` the field comes with this default value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it in `ViewsTable::beforeSave`

```
beforeSave($event, $entity, $options)
{
    if(!$entity->isNew() && !$entity->datetime)
    {
        $entity->datetime = Time::now();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I would do it with a behavior to use the code whenever it's needed.

Comment: Would not it be more interesting to the default value is set at the time of object creation? You may need to handle it during the business logic.

Comment: so I guess you can simply initialize your attribute in the `View::__construct()` method. I did a quick test and it seems to work. I'm not sure how and when cake invoke the constructor and if it performs some kind of manipulation to the entity after that so I'm not sure if it is a safe way to do it.