# CakePHP 4 - Entity Default Properties

Tags: cakephp

i try to set default values in the entity class of cakephp. In the docs i found nothing about that https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html. i know i can set values in the beforesave method [CakePHP 3 Entity default field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324059/cakephp-3-entity-default-field-value) but this is to late.

for example: i have a article entity class and i wont to create a articlenumber if it not send from the post data. in the validator is the number field marked as required.

```
$validator
            ->scalar('number')
            ->maxLength('number', 100)
            ->requirePresence('number',true)
            ->notEmptyString('number');
```

and the problem is now if i run the `$this->Articles->save()` method the beforesave method runs after the validation.
i tried it too this the constructor method in the entity https://api.cakephp.org/4.0/class-Cake.ORM.Entity.html#__construct but this perform everytime a error

> Too few arguments to function App\Model\Entity\Article::__construct(),
> 0 passed in
> /var/www/html/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Marshaller.php
> on line 185 and exactly 2 expected

i know too i can set the number in the controller if it is not set but in want to set it in the article entity class as a default value. this is one of many property examples.
i hope anyone have a solution for this problem.

Comment: read https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#Cake\ORM\Entity::set

Comment: Instead of `beforeSave`, perhaps `beforeRules` or `beforeMarshal` would be better options for this?

Comment: Yeah before marshal is actual the alternative that i use but i think it must give a way to use the constructor method of an entity or a other in the entity class

Comment: Entities work on a on demand basis usually, using the setter and getter customizations as documented.